# debug Flask server inside Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, flask, jupyter-notebook

I want to debug a small Flask server inside Jupyter Notebook for demo.

I created a virtualenv on the latest Ubuntu and Python 2 (on Mac with Python 3 this error occurs as well), pip install flask jupyter.

However, when I create a cell with “Hello World” script, it does not run inside notebook.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True,port=1234)
```

> ```
> File "/home/***/test/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py",
> line 177, in _bind_socket 
>     s.bind("tcp://%s:%i" % (self.ip, port))   
> File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 495, in
>     zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.bind
>    (zmq/backend/cython/socket.c:5653)   
> File "zmq/backend/cython/checkrc.pxd", line 25, in
>     zmq.backend.cython.checkrc._check_rc
>    (zmq/backend/cython/socket.c:10014)
>        raise ZMQError(errno) ZMQError: Address already in use
> ```

NB – I change the port number after each time it fails.

Sure, it runs as a standalone script.

**Update:**

Without `debug=True` it works OK.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I installed Jupyter and Flask and your original code works.

---

The `flask.Flask` object is a WSGI application, not a server. Flask uses Werkzeug's development server as a `WSGI` server when you call `python -m flask run` in your shell. It creates a new WSGI server and then passes your app as paremeter to `werkzeug.serving.run_simple`. Maybe you can try doing that manually:

```
from werkzeug.wrappers import Request, Response
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from werkzeug.serving import run_simple
    run_simple('localhost', 9000, app)
```

`Flask.run()` calls `run_simple()` internally, so there should be no difference here.

Comment: How do you run Flask from inside a Jupyter notebook? Please link to actual jupyter notebook and any related code. Thank you.

Comment: if that's being run on the Jupyter server, which is being run on port 8888 locally, how do you reach it?  http://localhost:9000 gives me nothing. Using the jupyter terminal and  # curl localhost:9000 gives me the response. I guess I need to set up an ssh tunnel to the Jupyter server

Comment: using 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost gives more options but none of those seem to work either

Comment: The first import in your code - `from werkzeug.wrappers import Request, Response` - is not used and may be omitted.

Comment: As OP in his question, in the **Update:** part of it wrote, without `debug=True` his code work. So it seems that the code in your answer is not a solution for OP's question.

Answer (score 3):

The trick is to run the Flask server in a separate thread. This code allows registering data providers. The key features are

- Find a free port for the server. If you run multiple instances of the server in different notebooks they would compete for the same port.
- The `register_data` function returns the URL of the server so you can use it for whatever you need.
- The server is started on-demand (when the first data provider is registered)
- *Note:* I added the `@cross_origin()` decorator from the `flask-cors` package. Else you cannot call the API form within the notebook.
- *Note:* there is no way to stop the server in this code...
- *Note:* The code uses typing and python `3`.
- *Note:* There is no good error handling at the moment

```py
import socket
import threading
import uuid
from typing import Any, Callable, cast, Optional

from flask import Flask, abort, jsonify
from flask_cors import cross_origin
from werkzeug.serving import run_simple

app = Flask('DataServer')


@app.route('/data/<id>')
@cross_origin()
def data(id: str) -> Any:
    func = _data.get(id)
    if not func:
        abort(400)
    return jsonify(func())


_data = {}

_port: int = 0


def register_data(f: Callable[[], Any], id: Optional[str] = None) -> str:
    """Sets a callback for data and returns a URL"""
    _start_sever()
    id = id or str(uuid.uuid4())
    _data[id] = f
    return f'http://localhost:{_port}/data/{id}'


def _init_port() -> int:
    """Creates a random free port."""
    # see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5089963/2297345
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.bind(('localhost', 0))

    port = sock.getsockname()[1]
    sock.close()
    return cast(int, port)


def _start_sever() -> None:
    """Starts a flask server in the background."""
    global _port
    if _port:
        return
    _port = _init_port()
    thread = threading.Thread(target=lambda: run_simple('localhost', _port, app))
    thread.start()
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused if this would be correct approach to use Jupiter Notebook with a Flask App. I started a Flask server and a notebook, but I keep getting the `RuntimeError: No application found` when trying to query a database using Flask-SQLAlchemy. Would your answer apply? Thanks.

Comment: This is a way to start a flask server from within a notebook.

Comment: is this just for running curl's to from within the notebook ? I'm not able to get to the localhost url in a browser

Answer (score 0):

Although this question was asked long ago, I come up with another suggestion:

The following code is adapted from how PyCharm starts a Flask console.

```
import sys
from flask.cli import ScriptInfo
app = None
locals().update(ScriptInfo(create_app=None).load_app().make_shell_context())
print("Python %s on %s\nApp: %s [%s]\nInstance: %s" % (sys.version, sys.platform, app.import_name, app.env, app.instance_path))
```

Now you can access `app` and use everything described in the Flask docs on [working with the shell](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/shell/)

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to [Peter_B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15746126/peter-b)'s answer, if you add the following lines you can test most of your app functionality:

```
ctx = app.app_context().push()
ctx = app.test_request_context().push()
```