# How to run Flask inside a Jupyter notebook block for easy testing?

Tags: python, flask, jupyter-notebook

I want to Run a Flask Server inside a jupyter notebook for specific test and QA scenarios. I do understand that it is not wise to run a server inside notebook(As mentioned in the comments of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52457582/flask-application-inside-jupyter-notebook)).

However, I want to test a specific function that both requires a flask `AppContext` and a running server. It is a third-party API webhook handler and the third party does not have method to generate fake webhooks. While this might be a very specific case, I think this question is worth asking for edge cases like mine.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a thread inside a block, with a target call of `app.run`. This will run the app in a separate thread.

```
from threading import Thread

Thread(target=app.run).start()
```

Restart the `ipykernel` as soon as you are done, and *DO NOT* in any circumstances use this in prduction